# Unable to push css in heroku service

Tags: python, html, css, django, heroku

## What I am doing ?

- I am trying to deploy a django web application on heroku server.

## Problem

- I am not able to push css files in heroku server using `git push heroku main` .
- When I remove css file from static folder, then everything is going well.

## more

- I have installed whitenoise too.....

```
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Post-processing 'CSS/style.css' failed!
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_31834d76/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 134, in collect
remote:            raise processed
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'CSS/images/mobile-app.png' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f8a24943cd0>.
remote:        The CSS file 'CSS/style.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          CSS/images/mobile-app.png
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to trichhpali.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/trichhpali.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/trichhpali.git'
```

**Thank you for your help** [image]

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't accept static files, you need to install Whitenoise and put it in settings.

See this doc and it'll work !

[Whitenoise doc](https://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)

[Heroku Whitenoise doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

P.S: after installing whitenoise, use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and update your requeriments

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

would work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be `whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError`. Whitenoise is looking for a file `CSS/images/mobile-app.png` referenced in your css file `CSS/style.css` . Because it can't find that file, it stops with the `ValueError`.

Solution would be to either to:

1. Update the place in your css file (`CSS/style.css`) where it is looking for `CSS/images/mobile-app.png`. Check that the url path where it is referenced is correct. e.g. It may really need to be `/images/mobile-app.png` instead of `CSS/images/mobile-app.png`.
2. Or add the missing file where it is expected (`CSS/images/mobile-app.png`).